# MS access Not In List event and Subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a survey form in ms access  2003 which have one main form and two subforms from 3 different tables. On the main form there is a combo box for patient ID and date field for date registered. when the patient ID is not in the list a the event fires and a pop up form appears where i can completer details of new ID and date and that new id will create a record in all 3 tables. My problem is after closing the popup form the combo box does show new data -ID but the subform which relates to the new ID does not update or refresh and does not show new ID. I need to close the main form and re-open and then i can select the new patient ID which will be shown on the subform as well. Can this be programmed so that i do not have to close the form? Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually re-populate all controls from code by executing the following in VBA code of you form:

```
Me.Requery
```

As long as your form is opened you can access the form via AllForms collection. So, in your popping-up form you can just write in the OnClose-event the following code

```
Forms("NameOfYourMainForm").Requery
```

Comment: Sorry Alaudo i tried this but is shows error sub or function not defined. and why brackets after Requery()?

Comment: It shows compile error sub or function not defined. Private Sub Command6_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command6_Click
 'Forms!MainForm!MaleTableSubform.Form.Requery
   AllForms(MainForm).Requery
   DoCmd.Close

Exit_Command6_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command6_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command6_Click
    
End Sub

Comment: i changed all forms to Forms and now it when close command is clicked it asks me if i want to add the data and when answered yes it closes main form and after i click the close button again it closes pop up form.

Comment: Don't you forget to use quotes while referencing your form? Not 'Forms(MainForm)' but 'Forms("MainForm")'.

Comment: Hi Alaudo i am sorry but still refuse to work. do you have sample database?

Comment: I have closed the example I quickly programmed to test my solution. Maybe if you post a sample db I could look at it?

Comment: Thanks for that. I have sent you the database example file

Comment: Thanks Aludo. I have managed to solve this problem by removing child and parent relations and using subform source from query.